# how to keep javascripts after UpdatePanel partial postback

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

There is a lot of code so I want to explain the issue shortly in words. I have a Master page, that includes all references to javascript files and have the pages that use the master page. I use update panel in my pages and inside the update panel there are some forms including that one-has postback capability(ie dropdownlist). The problem is when the state changes and a partial postback occurs, the forms which has some capabilities and effects because of those javascripts, then lose all the functionality. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the below link http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/09/use-jquery-and-ajax-with-aspnet-master.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because after the partial post back with the Update panel you need to re-initialize the javascript. Here is a general example

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   // if you use jQuery, you can load them when dom is read.
   $(document).ready(function () {
       var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
       prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
       prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

       // Place here the first init
    });        

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    }

    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
       // after update occur on UpdatePanel re-init what you need

    }
</script>
```

Relative questions:
[Asp.Net UpdatePanel in Gridview Jquery DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341623/asp-net-updatepanel-in-gridview-jquery-datepicker/3341741#3341741)
[How to get Id update panel that initial a request in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041169/how-to-get-id-update-panel-that-initial-a-request-in-javascript/10041337#10041337)

After the net 4 you can also simple use the `pageLoad` function, is similar to the OnLoad function, but is handled by asp.net and is called on the first page load, but also called after each ajax update.

```
function pageLoad()
{
    // init here your javascript
    // This is called when the page load first time
    //  and called again each time you have an Update inside an UpdatePanel
}
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386417(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This one was for me the direct approach that just simply worked. No brainer, just to find it here and test in my app. Thanks.